# Confusions about partial and covariant derivatives

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, differentiation

Let, we are in 1d cartesian space with metric $g_{xx} = x^2$. Let we have a vector $v = 1/x e_x$. Since the vector is designed to shrink its components as the basis grows - its total length will remain constant - meaning that it will be parallel transported along $x$ axis, and its covariant derivative will be zero. But what about its partial derivative (here just derivative because of 1d)?

Comment: What do you mean by partial derivative of a vector field?